# Aligning li links to bottom in navbar for Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 (flexbox)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So been trying to get a menu in my navbar to align to the bottom instead of the middle of the li.

As I have two menus, the top one is just a call us and a login, where as the bottom one is the sections of the webpage.

Now my issue is, how do I align the top menu to the bottom of the LI instead of centred. Tried align-text-bottom and align-bottom:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right align-self-center mt-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><object class="svgLogoBig" data="assets/svg/Logo.svg"></object></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar navbar-collapse flex-column ml-lg-0 ml-3" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar3">
                <H1 class="firstMenuLine navbar-nav ml-auto w-100">DBFS</H1>
                <ul class="firstMenuLine navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end align-baseline">
                    <li class="nav-item align-text-bottom">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="tel:555-555-555">Call Us Now: <span class="phoneNumber">555-555-555<span></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item align-bottom">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="open_login">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar3">
                <H2 class="secondMenuLine navbar-nav ml-auto w-100">Delivering Change                </H2>
                    <H2>
                    <ul class="secondMenuLine navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link py-1 pr-3" href="/news">Big1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link py-1 pr-3" href="/advice">Big2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link py-1 pr-3" href="#">Big3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link py-1 pr-3" href="/deliver">Big4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link py-1 pr-3" href="/career">Big5</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </H2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But neither one have an impact. I could just put possition absolute, but that seems to defeat the object of using flexbox. I am pretty certain that it is the li and not the ul that does the aligning, tried adding align-baseline as well, no luck.

Its the li's in this section I want to align to the bottom

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar3">
                    <H1 class="firstMenuLine navbar-nav ml-auto w-100">DBFS</H1>
                    <ul class="firstMenuLine navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end align-baseline">
                        <li class="nav-item align-text-bottom">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="tel:555-555-555">Call Us Now: <span class="phoneNumber">555-555-555<span></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item align-bottom">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="open_login">Login</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

If I inspect the object I can see that:

```
.align-text-bottom {
    vertical-align: text-bottom!important;
}
```

Comment: Can you post all of the navbar code. This is just the collapse portion.

Comment: Sorry about that, code above updated